# How to query to show all boss names

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

How to make query in ms access to show raid name and all it's bosses

[image]

Identyfikator - Id
Nazwa - Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r.Nazwa, b1.Nazwa AS BossName1, b2.Nazwa AS BossName2,
  b3.Nazwa AS BossName3, b4.Nazwa AS BossName4, b5.Nazwa AS BossName5
FROM ((((Raid AS r
  INNER JOIN Boss AS b1 ON r.Boss1 = b1.Identyfikator)
  INNER JOIN Boss AS b2 ON r.Boss2 = b2.Identyfikator)
  INNER JOIN Boss AS b3 ON r.Boss3 = b3.Identyfikator)
  INNER JOIN Boss AS b4 ON r.Boss4 = b4.Identyfikator)
  INNER JOIN Boss AS b5 ON r.Boss5 = b5.Identyfikator
```

Comment: figured it out, access wanted "inner" (not sure if it's proper way) before JOIN, thanks.

Comment: If you just specify join it usually means inner join so you are right.  I updated my answer to reflect what worked for you.